# Convert jarray to byte array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, json.net

I need to somehow convert jarray to a byte array in c# so I can display the appropriate image. The call is made via RESTful web service and in response I'm getting this (sample) value:

[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,96,0,96,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,4,2,3,3,3,2,4,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,9,6,5,5,5,5,11,8,8,6,9,13,11,13,13,13,11,12,12,14,16,20,17,14,15,19,15,12,12,18,24,18,19,21,22,23,23,23,14,17,25,27,25,22,26,20,22,23,22,255,219,0,67,1,4,4,4,5,5,5,10,6,6,10,22,15,12,15,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,255,192,0,17,8,0,67,0,100,3,1,34,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,31,0,0,1,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

NOTE: I trimmed the content of the value but this is the data I'm getting in response.
Now this is how I'm getting the value:

```
                foreach (JObject obj in arr)
                {
                    JArray jar = new JArray();                            
                    jar = obj["Thumbnail"] as JArray;
                  
                }
```

How I can convert that value to `byte[]` so I can display the image in mvc view?

Comment: Why are you creating a new `JArray` and then immediately ignoring it?

Comment: @JonSkeet I put jarray here only to show how I'm trying, if there's better way to consume the data feel free to let me know. Thanks

Comment: My point is that the body of your loop would be better as `JArray jar = obj["Thumbnail"] as JArray;`. Never just assign a value to a variable and then immediately assign a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use `String` methods and `LINQ` to get your byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = response.Trim('[', ']')
              .Split(',')
              .Select(x => byte.Parse(x))
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: what do I need to put instead of response in my case?

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] bytes = responce.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] byteItems = myJArray.Split(',').Select(z => byte.Parse(z)).ToArray();


If you dun't need to split then

byte[] byteItems = myJArray.Select(z => byte.Parse(z)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Did you mean to cast to `byte` instead of `int`?